# How do I avoid 'missing arguments' in instances and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, instance, self

I am currently writing a for school that should have 3 classes: Student, Teacher, School. (all of them in their own .py document).

The class "Teacher" holds a List of Name, subjects and Age

The class ''Student'' holds a List of Name, classes and student_IDs

The class "School'' is the class that brings them both together, it contains them.

Now if I call the instance method Student.print_list() it tells me I am lacking one Parameter.

What does the self do, why is it mandatory, how do I avoid having to enter parameters from other classes?

My second but same problem is when I want to print out one Teacher info, but have to send one parameter. Obviously then the self still does not work/it takes the first parameter I give it.

I have tried a bunch of things, but to no avail so far.
I have tried: Class methods(cheating), leaving the self(wrong), passing anything like list_students(False)(cheating). How do I legitematly solve this problem?

student.py

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, student_id, classes):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.classes = classes
        student_list = []
        student_list.append(Student('Nemo the Fish', '12-b-018241', 'english, maths, IT')            
    #a list of all student names etc. is entered here
```

school.py

```
import Student
class School:
    def print_list(self):
        for Student.Student in Student.student_list:
            print Student.Student.name
```

main.py

```
import school
print_list()
```

Obviously I would want a list of a bunch of names, but I get a 'missing 1 required positional argument: self'. I feel like what I did wrong is calling the method wrongly, because there must be a way to

have the (self) be there like its supposed to be

call the method without giving trash parameters

not use any @classmethod thing or anything alike

Comment: you have to instantiate the School class `school = School(); school.print_list()` and instantiate Student inside School aswell

Comment: @Ascurion I gotta say, I am retarded. Thank you that actually put my head free which was stuck in the wall i was running against

Comment: I'd say that the `student_list` attribute would better belong to the `School` class, because the school has a list of students, not the student....

Comment: Glad I could help! Please, consider accepting an answer if it works for you, so  people running against the same wall see faster what helped.

Answer (score 1):

The following would do what you want if I understood your provided code correctly:

student.py:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, student_id, classes):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.classes = classes
```

school.py:

```
from student import Student   
class School:
    def __init__(self):
        self.student_list = []
        self.student_list.append(Student('Nemo the Fish', '12-b-018241', 'english, maths, IT'))

    def print_list(self):
        for student in self.student_list:
             print(student.name)
```

main.py:

```
from school import School()
this_school = School()
this_school.print_list()
```

Although this is not the best approach to hardcode the list of students into the class definition.